# did they forget "must" in this sentence?

Tags: passive-voice

I encountered with this sentence in wikipedia

> as per new york state mandate masks are to be worn again

[here's the link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice)

Is this sentence gramatically correct? I am searching for a "must". here's how does this sentence should be written.

> as per new york state mandate masks are **must** be worn again.

Comment: When an official notice says that something _is to be_ done, it means that people must do it. (NB The notice is in block capitals, but in ordinary writing it's _New York State_.)

Comment: Also, you never use *must* and a conjugated verb form like *are* together.  *must* is always used with a bare infinitive, like *must be*, *must eat*, *must sleep*, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The be+infinitive construction expresses official rules and regulations or plans. The passive voice focusses on the consequence of action, rather than the actor. It is used when the actor is a government or organisation.

Further examples from http://www.grammaring.com/be-to-infinitive

> At the end of the course, all students are to take a written exam.

> You are not to do that again.

It can also be used to describe official plans:

> The Prime Minister is to visit India next month.

There is no need for a modal like "must".  However some of these could be rephrased with the modal

> All students must take a written exam.